# MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause (two joins)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I'm trying to update the unit_price in a sales_order_parts detail table with calculation from the  applied_discount field from sales_orders.  Also, the price is in the master_part_list table as price.  When I run from the select statement down, it runs fine and returns the list of values from order_number 209 with the correct calculation.  When I run it complete from the update line, it returns "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'sop' for update in FROM clause" Any ideas?

```
update sales_order_parts as sop
    set unit_price =
    (select (master_part_list.price * (1-(so.applied_discount/100)))
    from sales_orders as so
        inner join sales_order_parts as sop2 
            on so.id = sop2.order_id
        inner join master_part_list 
            on sop2.part_id = master_part_list.id
        where so.order_number = 209);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a join without subquery

```
update sales_order_parts as sop
INNER JOIN sales_orders as so on so.id = sop.order_id
  AND so.order_number = 209 
inner join master_part_list on sop.part_id = master_part_list.id
SET sop.unit_price = master_part_list.price * (1-(so.applied_discount/100))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  I had to set rounding on the set.  SET sop.unit_price2 = round((master_part_list.price * (1-(so.applied_discount/100))),2);

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery for sales_order_parts. mysql then treats as new temporary table

Like

```
update sales_order_parts as sop
    set unit_price =
    (select (master_part_list.price * (1-(so.applied_discount/100)))
    from sales_orders as so
        inner join (SELECT * FROM sales_order_parts) as sop2 
            on so.id = sop2.order_id
        inner join master_part_list 
            on sop2.part_id = master_part_list.id
        where so.order_number = 209);
```

Comment: mysql accepted this code, but when I ran the complete code, I get the message "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Run your SELECT Query before hand, if you get more than one Result row, Limit it to one and order it to get the wanted result.

Comment: The query returns 4 rows (there are 4 line items to this order 209).  I tried to be more specific, but still get the error code 1242. 
```
update sales_order_parts as sop
    set unit_price =
    (select (master_part_list.price * (1-(so.applied_discount/100)))
    from sales_orders as so
        inner join (SELECT * FROM sales_order_parts) as sop2 
            on so.id = sop2.order_id
        inner join master_part_list 
            on sop2.part_id = master_part_list.id
        where so.order_number = 209 
        and sop2.part_id = master_part_list.id);
```

Comment: I wanted it ro run through these 4 lines (or as many lines on different order) and update the price with the applied discount.

Comment: A unit can only have one price as statet in your query. Now you can make a max or an average or whatever you like, but the result must be 1 value tto pout into unit-price, if you want to have more prices make teh column a json datatype and asave as many as you like.